# Ruby on Rails server doesn't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to takeover an existing Ruby on Rails website and to finish it. I'm very new to this, and have some problems.

I can't even start the server from the terminal, I suspect it is a version related problem, since I've just configured my computer to work with Ruby on Rails, and the website development begun a year or two ago. If I create and work on a project myself, everything works fine. I'm on MacBook under OSX Mavericks.

Here are some specifics:

To start the server I go into the project directory with my terminal and type:

```
rails server
```

This command gives me the following error message:

```
/Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Davydov/CodingSpace/RubyWorkspace/celliptic/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I've of course looking around the internet about this problem, for a long time and somebody told to run this:

```
bundle install
```

If I understand well this reinstalls all the gems, and at the end I get an error message like that:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config
--with-mysql-dir
--without-mysql-dir
--with-mysql-include
--without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
--with-mysql-lib
--without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mlib
--without-mlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-zlib
--without-zlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-socketlib
--without-socketlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-nsllib
--without-nsllib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mygcclib
--without-mygcclib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Davydov/CodingSpace/RubyWorkspace/celliptic/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Davydov/CodingSpace/RubyWorkspace/celliptic/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_    64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.11/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This error message suggests that I should run, and make sure this succeeds before bundling:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11
```

And this is what I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/Davydov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config
--with-mysql-dir
--without-mysql-dir
--with-mysql-include
--without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
--with-mysql-lib
--without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mlib
--without-mlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-zlib
--without-zlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-socketlib
--without-socketlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-nsllib
--without-nsllib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mygcclib
--without-mygcclib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Davydov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Davydov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.11/gem_make.out
```

At this moment I'm stuck and don't know what to do. All kind of help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I believe there are many related questions related to mysql2 gem installation problems

Comment: Do you have mysql installed?

Comment: In short, you need to install the mysql binaries and libraries first using something like homebrew (`brew install mysql`).

Comment: thanks guys, this solved it! It's been days, can't believe I was so dumb, thank you very much